# Update field for new entries only

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am trying to work out a way to be able to update the Unit Code for any new Unit Offerings but keep the original unit code for the Unit Offerings which have already been created.

I.E if the unit code changes between years the subject is offered I want the unit code to reflect what was the accurate code at the time the unit offering was created.

Here are my tables

```
CREATE TABLE Units (
    UnitsID                 INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    UnitsName               VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    UnitsCode               VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (UnitsID)
);

CREATE TABLE UnitsOffering (
    UOfferingID             INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    UOUnits                 INT(10) NOT NULL, 
    YIIntake                VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    YIYear                  INT(4) NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY             (UOfferingID),
    FOREIGN KEY             (UOUnits) REFERENCES Units(UnitsID)
);
```

I can get it updated with my current stored procedure, but when I list the unit offering and unit details, it reflects the new unit code, not the code in the database when the offering was created.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateUnit(IN vUnitsID VARCHAR (255), IN vUnitsCode VARCHAR (20))
BEGIN
UPDATE Units 
SET UnitsCode = vUnitsCode
WHERE UnitsID = vUnitsID;
 END;
```

Here is the select statement I'm using when creating my list.

```
SELECT  O.UOfferingID, U.UnitsCode, U.UnitsName, O.YIIntake, O.YIYear
        FROM (UnitsOffering O
        INNER JOIN Units U
        ON  O.UOUnits = U.UnitsID)
        ORDER BY O.UOfferingID;
```

I am not sure if this can actually be done. If it can I am not sure if there is a problem with the way my tables are set up, with my update statement or with my list statement.

Any help would be much appreciated. I have tried to look into some documentation for how this can be done but I can't find the right keywords.

An example of what I want to be able to list is below. For this example shows what I want it to show if there was a change in the unit code after 2021 was finished.

```
COS10000 - Introduction to Programming - Semester 2 2021
INF30011 - Database Implementation -  Semester 1 2022
COS10059 - Introduction to Programming  - Semester 2 2022
```

Comment: Use a left join

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected result.

Comment: I've tried a left join but it doesn't work. Lists still only show the most recent unit code, not the unit code that was in the table when the unit offering was entered

Comment: When you update your `Unit` the existing `UnitCode` is beeing replaced by the new one, and the initial value is lost. Depending on your needs you might store `UnitsCodeInitial` and `UnitsCodeEffective` instead of one value, or you might create a separate table that stores all changes to `Unit`'s codes.

Comment: Your initial sentence makes no sense, to me. How can you update anything if it hasn't already been created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible approaches:

1. When creating a new record in UnitsOffering, physically write the UnitCode value to the record (in a new column) rather than linking to a value in the Units table via an FK
2. Redesign the Units table so that it holds history e.g. all changes are treated as inserts, not updates and there are start/end dates for each record (or some other mechanism to identify when a record is the current version). There would then need to be logic to ensure the correct value is written to UnitsOffering.UOUnits